# How to parse delimited files to be compared

Tags: c#, string, parsing

There is a text file formatted like the example below that I need to search for a students class name:

```
Michael | Straham | Eng101(4.0) | Mth303
Jacob | Black | SCI 210 (2.3) | Eng101
Ian | Summers | Mth303(3.30) | Sci 210
```

The delimited symbols are ( | )

The class names are "ENG101, SCI210, MTH303." I would like to search each line from the text for that class name and somehow index them so that they can be compared. The end result would be this:

```
ENG101:
Michael Straham, Jacob Black
```

Please assist. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post what you have tried.  Right now it seems like you are just asking us to write the whole thing for you.

Comment: Your 'result' does not match your data. Please fix it, this only leads to confusion.

Comment: @Abe Haven't really done anything and I don't know how to parse the text. Definitely not asking to write it all. I just need to know how to pull class names so I can keep working.

Comment: Use String.Split(new char {'|'}) to get an array of strings, each one being one of your delimited strings. This of course sets a constraint on your input data not to have any vertical lines in them for other purposes than delimiting. If you do you need to escape these.

Comment: @SamiHuutoniemi so would this return everything within the |  |'s? If so that may work!

Comment: Just check the link for an example.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're already reading in the input line by line.

You can use String.Split() to accomplish (the first part of) what you are trying to do.

For example, the following code

```
String s1 = "Michael | Straham | Eng101(4.0) | Mth303";
char[] separators = { '|' };
String[] values = s1.Split(separators);
```

would give you an array of 4 strings ( "Michael", "Straham", "Eng101(4.0)", "Mth303"). You can then analyze the values array to see who is in which class. I'd probably have code roughly that looks like this (in pseudocode):

```
foreach (line in input)
{ 
    String s1 = line;
    char[] separators = { '|' };
    String[] values = s1.Split(separators);

    String firstName = values[0];
    String lastName = values[1];

    for (i = 2, i < values.length)
    {
        if (values[i] looks like "ENG101")
        {
           add firstName lastName to "ENG101" student list
        }
        else if (values[i] looks like "MTH303")
        {
           ....
        }
        ....
    }
}
```